# Angular: Send data from component to another component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular, I have these components:

**MainComponent.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {UsersTableComponent} from './UsersTableComponent';
import {UserAddComponent} from './UserAddComponent';

@Component({
    selector: 'main',
    templateUrl: '../app/views/mainView.html',
    directives: [UsersTableComponent, UserAddComponent]
})

export class MainComponent {
    constructor() {}
}
```

**UserAddComponent.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {GenderPipe} from '../pipes/GenderPipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'userAdd',
    templateUrl: '../app/views/userAdd.html',
    pipes: [GenderPipe]
})

export class UserAddComponent {
    constructor() {}

    addUser() {
        alert(1);
    }
}
```

**UserTableComponent**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {UserServices} from '../services/UserServices';
import {User} from '../classes/User';
import {GenderPipe} from '../pipes/GenderPipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'usersTable',
    templateUrl: '../app/views/usersTable.html',
    pipes: [GenderPipe]
})

export class UsersTableComponent {
    users: Array<User>

    constructor(UserServices: UserServices) {
        this.users = UserServices.getUsers();
    }
}
```

on the `UserAddComponent` on addUser method I need to read some values from the template and update users though `UserServices`. When it is updated, I need to call a method from the UserTableComponent in order to refresh a table with the data added to the users.

How can I call a method in one component from another component?

Answer (score 4):

Have the parent of both components hold the list of `users` in a property and pass it to both children components using `@Input`, that way both will react whenever the list changes:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html

Alternative you can throw an event with `@Output`:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Output-var.html

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event (user added) in the user service. When the response is received from the user service (add an element), it can call the `emit` method of the corresponding event emitter. the `UserTableComponent` component can register on this event using the `subscribe` method to be notified when the event is fired.

Another approach would be to trigger this 'user added' event from the `UserAddComponent` component itself:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class UserAddComponent {
  @Output() userAdded;

  constructor(private service:UserService) {
  }

  addUser() {
    // user is linked to a form for example
    this.service.addUser(this.user).subscribe(
      (addedUserData) => {
        this.userAdded.emit(addedUserData);
      }
  }
}
```

The other component (the table one) can use the event like this:

```
<add-user (user-added)="refreshTable()"></add-user>
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Super annoying when people downvote without leaving a comment why :-/

Comment: I don't know why I think its a valid alternative, I even mentioned it myself. But my feedback is that this way you are breaking the whole purpose of binding. It has its uses but if you were to emit and subscribe to each change between components why would you use a binding framework in the first place?

Comment: @Langley: I see exactly what you mean... We could add the response content into the list the array is bound on. The problem is that we could have observable and async pipe that are used to display the list...

Comment: But that observable can be anywhere, might as well be in the parent and feed the children with them right?

Comment: @Langley: Yes but I mean how to add new values in a loop for example that leverages the async pipe. Data were initially loaded from an HTTP request for example and then how to add an element to the list without executing again the HTTP request...