# Sending calculated data from one component to another without Services

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to send the value from one component to another, they are not related so all solutions are saying that I must use shared service to do that. But these services are using templates (if I'm right). Is there a way to do this sharing without services?

I want to send the BMI value from homepage.component.ts to result.component.ts.

homepage.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.css']
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

myHeight!:number;
myWeight!:number;

bmi!:number;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onGenerate(  height:string,width:string){

    this.myHeight = +height;
    this.myHeight=Math.pow(this.myHeight/100,2);

    this.myWeight = +width;
    this.bmi=this.myWeight/this.myHeight


console.log(this.bmi); //this is the calculated value to send

  }
}
```

result.component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-result',
      templateUrl: './result.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./result.component.css']
    })
    export class ResultComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor() { }
    
//I want to get the bmi here
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Service does not uses template only data if you right that way.

Comment: Please only use tags that are relevant to your post. [Angular](https://angular.io/) is a very different framework from [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org), and now discontinued framework.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs / https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-passing-data-child-component/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: Send data from component to another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880261/angular-send-data-from-component-to-another-component)

Comment: @HereticMonkey UserTableComponent is using sevices( import {UserServices} from '../services/UserServices'; )

Comment: @RaviAshara it's for related components

Comment: And? That has nothing to do with the answers. It's not using the service to share data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your components are not related then you can create a shared service between them. Then, you need to use dependency injection to communicate between these components. So, [there is a great Angular tutorial which describes how to do it.](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service)

The service code would look like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class FooService {

  constructor(  ) { }

  private yourData;

  setData(data){
    this.yourData = data;
  }

  getData(){
    let temp = this.yourData;
    this.clearData();
    return temp;
  }
}
```

and sender component:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FooService} from './services/foo.service';

export class SenderComponent implements OnInit {         
  constructor(
    private fooService: FooService,
    private router:Router) {}

  somefunction(data){
   this.fooService.setData(data);
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/reciever');//as per router
 }
}
```

and subscriber:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TransfereService } from './services/transfer.service';

export class RecieverComponent implements OnInit {  
    data;

    constructor(
        private fooService: FooService){
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        data = this.transfereService.getData();     
        console.log(`data: `, data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the only way is to define homepage as the parent of result component?

Comment: @readJohn no, there is no need to do. Please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

There are Two ways to communicate between unrelated components in angular:

1 - Through services, you have to understand where to inject it, in your case I think it should be injected in root, so try this with your service ( follow this [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service) to implement your service, just add my code instead of theirs )

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

2 - Through a [store](https://ngrx.io/) ( a lot of boilerplate coding, to use if you have complexe states to keep synchronized through the whole app, by the way the store is basically a service )

Comment: Managing a store is clearly the good solution here. But it's more complicated and will need more code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to make it parent/child

Comment: @readJohn No need for to have them parent/child, providedIn: 'root' makes the service available in the whole app, no matter where you inject it

Comment: just make sure to inject it in the constructor of your component

Answer (score 0):

Solution: To pass the data from one component to another we can store it in a session storage or a local storage and then access it in other components from that storage. Here I have provided a sample code using local storage for your reference.

homepage.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.css']
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

myHeight!:number;
myWeight!:number;
data:string='';

bmi!:number;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onGenerate(  height:string,width:string){

    this.myHeight = +height;
    this.myHeight=Math.pow(this.myHeight/100,2);

    this.myWeight = +width;
    this.bmi=this.myWeight/this.myHeight;
    this.data=localStorage.setItem('bmi',this.bmi);


    console.log(this.bmi); //this is the calculated value to send

    }
    }
```

resultcomponent.ts:

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-result',
      templateUrl: './result.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./result.component.css']
    })
    export class ResultComponent implements OnInit {
     data:any;
      constructor() { this.data=localstorage.getItem('bmi')}
    
      //Access the bmi using the data variable here

      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    }
```